# A convex polyhedron has exactly $2$ decagonal faces and in each of vertices $4$ edges come together. Prove that it has at least $20$ triangular faces.

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra

A convex polyhedron has exactly $2$ decagonal faces and in each of its vertices has exactly $4$ edges coming together. Prove that this polyhedron has at least $20$ triangular faces.

Let's call:

- v = number of vertices;
- e = number of edges;
- f = number of faces.

From eulers equation I know that: $v - e + f = 2$

We know also that: $2e = 4v$ since there are $2$ vertices incident with $1$ egde and $4$ edges coming together in $1$ vertice.

But how to prove that there are at least $20$ triangular faces knowing that there are exactly $2$ decagonal faces? I don't even know anything about the other possible faces of that polyhedron.

Comment: Possibly helpful: The decagonal diprism  has exactly $20$ triangular faces.

Comment: It's more about the decagonal antiprism. It has 2 decagons + 20 triangles, as well as 4 edges per vertex throughout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the polyhedron has $V$ vertices, $E$ edges and $F$ faces in total. We know that $2$ of these are decagons; say $F_3$ are triangles and $F'$ are neither triangles nor decagons (so $F=2+F_3+F'$). Importantly, these other faces have at least $4$ sides.

Not only do we have $2E=4V$, as you say, by counting the vertices on each face we also have $2\cdot 10+3F_3+4F' \le 4V$ (this is the key observation).

Now, by Euler's formula,
$$\begin{align} F+V&=E+2 \\
F+V&=2V+2 \\
F&=V+2 \\
F&\ge \frac14 \left[20+3F_3+4F'\right]+2 \\
2+F_3+F' &\ge 5+\frac34 F_3 + F'+2 \\
\frac14 F_3 &\ge 5
\end{align}$$

and so $F_3 \ge 20$, as required.